# My Azure function is not updated when I deploy it

Tags: azure-functions

I have written a Queue Triggered function but I am seriously thinking that it is not working even if I do not get any error. 
I explain the context where I am working and what I have done.

I have a queue... for some reason I have to insert about 200 messages per time in the queue. So, my function will run about 200 times almost at once.
The main method of the function is static. I do not like that... So I have created a class and all the logic of the function is there:

```
public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger(Program.CONST_QUEUENAME)]string queueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    try
    {
        log.Info($"Start: {queueItem}");

        await new MyFunction(log).ExecuteAsync(queueItem);

        log.Info($"End");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error($"Errore: {ex.Message}");

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In the `ExecuteAsync` method of my `MyFunction` class I do the following step:

- Deserializing the message
- Doing some check between the deserialied item and some data stored on db
- if check are ok, calling an api. The api, update another db
- After api call, I execute `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` to ensure that the call has been ok.

The result of function execution is NOTHING! Nothing is updated on database. Ok, I do some check to decide if I have to update the database or not.. but I expect that at least one update happens.

So I updated the function adding a lot of log message (I log using application insight) and what I discovered:

- about 200 messages are written on the queue (so, the problem is not on writing the queue)
- the function is executed correctly about 200 times
- I see an anomaly... it's like I am running an old version of the function. I do not see all new log messages. Obviously I deployed the new version of the function.

So what's wrong?

I just haeva doubt about publication... after I deploy it on azure (via VS) i receive this message:

> The version of Functions on your Azure host does not match the local
>   version. The application setting for FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION
>   should be updated to "~1". Update Azure application settings to match
>   local Functions version?
>   --------------------------- YES NO

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: You seem to have created v1 function locally,  while on Azure its host version is v2. Did you choose yes to change azure host version to ~1(v1)?

Comment: yes, i chosed yes... what do I have to modify to update the function to v2 locally?

Comment: What version of the Azure functions core tools are you using?

Comment: Specifically, what version of the nugget package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions does your .csproj file refer to?

Comment: @ConnorMcMahon  I am using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.14

Comment: @Ciccio Could you add your .csproj content? Have you run locally? When you debug locally, see the output `Starting Host (HostId=xxx, Version=1.0.11820.0, InstanceId=xxx....)`  The version is your function host version.

Comment: `Starting Host (HostId=xxx, Version=1.0.11702.0, ... FunctionsExtensionVersion=)`